# Django-rest-framework works but looks ugly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

So I´m building an API and I launched it in an online server. When I host the API in my localhost, it looks just fine but when I access it through the online server, it displays the information but kinda in a pure HTML way. It works fine but it kinda bothers me that it looks like that. Do I need to change something in my settings or has anyone else experienced something similar? Here's how it looks:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei4MU.jpg)

Comment: try `python manage.py collectstatic` and ensure your static dirs are set up correctly

Comment: Tried it already... no luck. It does copy some files into the "/static" folder but still no changes. Maybe there's something else I need to do?

Comment: Depending on where you deploy, you might need to use whitenoise to serve static files.